# What does "api.cache(true)" do in Expo's babel.config.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, expo

This line appears in the default Expo `babel.config.js`, but I can't find any reference anywhere to what it does. Is there anyone who knows what this does?

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default, Babel will evaluate configuration each time it processes a new file. It is possible to optimize the build process performance by caching config function execution result. `api.cache(true)` does exactly that. When the cache is enabled this way, config function will be called only once.

Here is a link for a more detailed explanation of Babel configuration caching: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#apicache